# VSCode terminal switch when debugging

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code

A seemingly recent behavior change is that when launching a nodejs debug session in VSCode it creates and switches to a new terminal window. The problem is the new terminal has different env vars than my normal one, so if I had pasted in AWS credentials, they are not known to the new terminal.
I checked my settings and my term is set to `integrated` and my launch.json file has `"console": "integratedTerminal",`
Can anyone confirm/deny a change?  I generally stay up to date an I am currently on 1.37.1 on my Mac.
I have now removed the `console` line from my launch.json.

Comment: Yep. VSCode has always done that, at least for a long while. I don't believe that aspect is configurable...

Comment: I don't think it has, or perhaps something else happened.  We get a bash command to enter our AWS credentials into the terminal and then we run our server code from the VSCode debugger and our server used to see the credentials, now it doesn't.  Something changed, though I am not sure what.